# OAUTH2 api not redirect as expected when deployed on azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deployed an API on Azure app service, this API uses Linkedin oauth2 to auth users. However, after Linkedin send back the token, the page does not redirect back to /dashboard and return an HTTP 500. Any solution for this?

my site : 
https://myapiv1test.azurewebsites.net/auth/linkedin/

my code: 
https://github.com/allan9595/api-linkedin-test

I deployed the same API on heroku and local, and all worked as expected.

https://myapiv1test.herokuapp.com/auth/linkedin

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to), currently the only supported (AAD, Facebook, Google, Microsoft Account, Twitter) identities for authentication provider. Checkout this Uservoice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/13286541-enable-custom-3rd-party-authentication-providers for a feedback on LinkedIn support, you may up-vote and comment your requirement.